# How to modify a TextureRegion in andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

Is it possible to change a textureRegion previously created? Like for example making a hole in the middle.

The only thing i ve come up with was: To use a single transparent pixel image and locate it overlapping a position in the `BitmapTextureAtlas`. But it would need thousands of overlappings!! It seems like a really expensive process.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should this hole be always in the same place or totally random?

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka Sorry but i may not be understanding the question. Do you mean if i would change the textureRegion many times?

Comment: What did you try? Any code? Just as experiment: Did you try to put empty (transparent) ping texture in your atlas overlapping other texture, to check if it will make a hole in it?